# Configuration object in Package json

Tags: json, object, configuration, package

I installed an package, https://github.com/VladimirMikulic/parcel-plugin-custom-dist-structure, in order to help me with my file structure in the dist folder for my project. I'm using parcel to bundle my project, but the images when are move into the dist folder, they arent in the img folder, but appear in the dist folder, among the index html. The package above should help me with this problem. But i cant figure it out or to find , some clarification on how to add this configuration object in package.json , as is written in the instructions.

My question is , how to i add that configuration in the package json?

```
Thank you!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUwae.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the customDistStructure to the package.json, like this:

```
{
    "name": "parcel-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "parce src/index.js --public-url .",
        "prod": "parcel build src/index.js --public-url .",
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
        "parcel-plugin-custom-dist-structure": "^1.1.18",
        "parcel-plugin-purgecss": "^3.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.34.0"
    },
    "customDistStructure": {
        "config": {
            "imgs": [
                ".jpg",
                ".png",
                ".svg",
                ".gif"
            ],
            "js": [
                ".js",
                ".js.map"
            ],
            "css": [
                ".css",
                ".css.map"
            ]
        },
        "options": {
            "development": true
        }
    }
}
```